# jquery data attribute as selector: how to get value from attribute inside onclick function?

Tags: jquery, selector

can anyone help which the best way to get the value from data attribute?

```js
$('[data-scrollTo]').on('click', function(event) {
    $(document).scrollTo('#'+#DATA?, {duration:'slow'});
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a data-scrollTo="#scrolltome" href="#">test</a>

<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div id="scrolltome"></div>
```

how i can get the value (shortest way) ?

Comment: $(document).scrollTo(?DATA?, {duration:'slow'});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `this` and `data()` as already suggested. The catch is that *scrollto* needs to be specified in lowercase letters.

```
$(this).data('scrollto');
```

As to your snippet... `scrollTo()` is not part of jQuery but probably one of its plugins. To do it natively with jQuery only, use `scrollTop()`:

```js
$('[data-scrollTo]').on('click', function(event) {
   $('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $($(this).data('scrollto')).offset().top
   }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a data-scrollTo="#scrolltome" href="#">scroll to target</a>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="scrolltome">target</div>
```

Comment: works great :-) THANK YOU!

yeah i you the scrollTo feature:  $('html, body').scrollTo($($(this).data('smoothscrollto')) , {duration:'slow'});

works great, thx again! that was the magic: $($(this).data('scrollto'))

Answer (score 0):

use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

`this.data('scrollTo');`

Comment: this i have already try and become an error: alert( this.data('scrollTo') ); (type error undefinded in not a function)